# Activator.CreateInstance calling constructor but returning null

Tags: c#, reflection, activator

I'm trying to create an instance of a generic type. I've tried getting the constructor through reflection, and now the way you'll see below, and both times the resulting object has been null.

```
Type type = typeof(StatDefinition<>).MakeGenericType(statTypes[selectedType]);
object definitionObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type, newName, newDescription);

StatTopic.WriteLine(definitionObject);
```

To help understand the variables, statTypes[selectedType] is just a basic type (bool, int, float, etc.). For my testing, it has always been typeof(float). 'newName' and 'newDescription' are both strings.

The constructor for StatDefinition<> is:

```
public StatDefinition(string name, string description) : base(name, description)
{ 
    StatTopic.WriteLine(typeof(T)); 
}
```

My console is first outputting 'System.Single' (from the constructor of StatDefinition), following by 'null' (definitionObject is null).

I cannot seem to find the reason for this, the constructor is obviously being called without issue, yet the new object isn't being returned.

EDIT: The stat definition class extends Unity3D's 'ScriptableObject' class and that seems to be the issue. Still not sure how to get around that

Comment: You may want to try `Activator.CreateInstance(type, new object [] { newName, newDescription });`

Comment: Thanks, but I have the exact same issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: So if you put a breakpoint on the line `StatTopic.WriteLine(definitionObject);` does it show that `definitionObject` is null?

Comment: I am sure There is something wrong on the code that you did not posted here. Try specifying whole piece of code that is related to this question here This fiddle works fine for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/hejCNM

Comment: Turns out extending the 'ScriptableObject' class (from Unity3D) is what's causing the issue. Not exactly sure why, nor whether it's worth keeping this question open given the context seems vastly different now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out extending the 'ScriptableObject' class (from Unity3D) is what's causing the issue.

Seems to be based on the way Unity must initialize their objects.